# Dynamic Side menu using three tier

Tags: c#, three-tier

Can anyone please provide the complete c# codes for a data driven  side menu in three tier architecture.i have tried for that but I don't know how to make menu dynamic

Comment: could you share what you have tried so far? Also a little more context about this would be helpful, for example what you're using to make the UI. see : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem or an interview question to me.